# Bootstrap 4 | Carousel text and image seperate

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have tried to accomplish the slider in the image. I also used the Bootstrap carousel, but the image size was always different, as well as the text on the left was jumping on top and then to the position where it belongs.

The text on the left (long text) was with the slider and was jumping back and forth, until it hits the right position. `About Us` and `Who are we`, were excluded from the slider.

Anyone has an idea to accomplish such a carousel/slider?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #232c41;
}

.bg {
  background: #3f9aa6;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.ml-right {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.mid_bar {
  background: #39435d;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #e7ffff;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #e7ffff;
}

.space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.d-flex {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rd_bottom_right {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-right: 35%;
}

.rd_bottom_left {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.rd_au {
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e7ffff;
  z-index: 999;
}

.rd_wwa {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  color: #fdbc4a;
  z-index: 998;
}

.ruttery {
  width: 40%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e7ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>RD - Raining Dreams</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- top bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto ml-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </form>
    </nav>
    <!-- actually the navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md mid_bar">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="main-navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forum</a>
          </li>
          <img class="navbar-brand space" src="img/mid_logo.png" alt="">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#server">Server</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- slider -->
    <div id="rd_slider_full" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev rd_bottom_left" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next rd_bottom_right" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      <!-- about us -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h2 class="rd_au">About Us</h2>
            <p class="rd_wwa">Who we are</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image: attachment]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add the code that you tried, including HTML & CSS & which version of Bootstrap (4.3.1?) so that anyone trying to assist you can reproduce the code locally if they need to. Check out SO Help Center FAQ for guidelines >>> [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure I truly understand what you are asking, but I can tell you that you are missing closing tags in your html, this may be causing some issues in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood that, you might have wanted your carousel `text` is on the left side then `photos` on the right side. I used `bootstrap grid` here to make two-column as **text column** and **slides column**. Photos are not responsive, I just added height to check if they are working properly, you can modify that as per your requirement.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #232c41;
}

.bg {
  background: #3f9aa6;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.ml-right {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.mid_bar {
  background: #39435d;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #e7ffff;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #e7ffff;
}

.space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.d-flex {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rd_bottom_right {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-right: 35%;
}

.rd_bottom_left {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.rd_au {
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e7ffff;
  z-index: 999;
}

.rd_wwa {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  color: #fdbc4a;
  z-index: 998;
}

.ruttery {
  width: 40%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e7ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>RD - Raining Dreams</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <body>
       <!-- top bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto ml-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </form>
    </nav>
    <!-- actually the navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md mid_bar">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="main-navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forum</a>
          </li>
          <img class="navbar-brand space" src="img/mid_logo.png" alt="">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#server">Server</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
<!--slider and text-->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <!-- text -->
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="rd_au">About Us</h2>
            <p class="rd_wwa">Who we are</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
<!-- slider -->
<div id="rd_slider_full" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080'); height:120px">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080'); height:120px">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080'); height:120px">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev rd_bottom_left" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next rd_bottom_right" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Let me explain again.

I want to have 2 sliders. One at the top of the page as a full screen slider. The second one, should be in the section "About us".

The text and the photos should slide with each click, so that every photo shows a different text on the left side. The text "About us and who we are" aren't included in the slider. 

With this I have trouble and do not know how I can do this. I tried also to "break" the caption text out of the slider and put it on the left side. 

Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding your question, I cleaned up the html (Added missing closing tags), used some bootstrap styles and moved the bottom block outside the carousel block.  Not entirely sure this is what you are looking for but hopefully it helps.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #232c41;
}

.bg {
  background: #3f9aa6;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.ml-right {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.mid_bar {
  background: #39435d;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #e7ffff;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #e7ffff;
}

.space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.d-flex {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rd_bottom_right {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.rd_bottom_left {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.rd_au {
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e7ffff;
  z-index: 999;
}

.rd_wwa {
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  color: #fdbc4a;
  z-index: 998;
}

.ruttery {
  width: 40%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e7ffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- top bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg">
  <img class="navbar-brand" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
  <form class="form-inline ml-auto ml-right">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  </form>
</nav>
<!-- actually the navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md mid_bar">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <img class="navbar-brand space" src="img/mid_logo.png" alt="">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#server">Server</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- slider -->
<div id="rd_slider_full" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev rd_bottom_left" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next rd_bottom_right" href="#rd_slider_full" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!-- about us -->

</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="rd_au ml-5">About Us</h2>
      <p class="rd_wwa ml-5">Who we are</p>
      <p class="text-white mx-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a vulputate enim, sit amet molestie mi. Nam auctor nec turpis id auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut suscipit
        libero ante, eget lacinia mauris dapibus vel. Cras at porta ex. Curabitur lacus ipsum, consequat vitae ligula imperdiet, molestie fermentum felis. Duis pretium feugiat erat, nec imperdiet enim dignissim imperdiet. Nullam non tortor vestibulum,
        tincidunt risus vitae, elementum velit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me explain again. I want to have 2 sliders. One at the top of the page as a full screen slider. The second one, should be in the section "About us". The text and the photos should slide with each click, so that every photo shows a different text on the left side. The text "About us and who we are" aren't included in the slider. With this I have trouble and do not know how I can do this. I tried also to "break" the caption text out of the slider and put it on the left side. Thanks for the help so far! –